# how to move files with numeric key words to corresponding folders using bash terminal script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a question about how to move files to specific folders according to their key words.
Say, I have a bunch of files:
R01.fastq.gz
R02.fastq.gz
R03.fastq.gz
R04.fastq.gz
...
and I have a buch of folder:
data01
data02
data03
data04
...
I want to put R01.fastq.gz to data01, R02.fastq.gz to data02, R03.fastq.gz to data03, R04.fastq.gz to data04 ...
So how to use a loop script to do it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
# use brace expansion to create a list 00,01,02,[...] 98,99
for i in {0..9}{0..9} ; do
  # defining file and directory as vars as we will use them a couple of times each
  F=R$i.fastq.gz
  D=data$i/
  # if F does not exist, or is not a file, do nothing
  [ -f $F ] || continue
  # create any needed directories and move files if created OK (mkdir
  # will fail if D exists but is not a directory)
  mkdir -p $D && mv $F $D
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much, so what does '[ -f $F ] || continue' mean? Could you explain this part a little bit?

Comment: It makes it skip the iteration of the loop when F doesn’t exist as a file.

Comment: It could otherwise have been written: `! test -f $F && continue`